# Receiving key error when parsing json response for an existing key

Tags: python

Ok so I am working on a very simple restAPI for one of my software packages. However when attempting to find the 'mac' key in the response from the API, it is present, but a statement such as `if 'mac' in retget:` can't seem to locate the 'mac' key and just returns a key error. Here is the json response from the api:

```
{u'result': {u'mac': u'238368712447488', u'key': u'123'}}
```

Also here is the entire script that is getting a response from the API and searching for the 'mac' key. (Note some of the code is useless to this task but is just there for things that will be present later in the script)

```
from uuid import getnode as get_mac
import os.path
import requests
import json

usermac = get_mac()
strusermac = str(usermac)
print strusermac
key = raw_input('Enter your key: ')


main_api = "http://127.0.0.1:3134/auth/%s"%(key)
retget = requests.get(main_api).json()
print retget


if 'mac' in retget:
    print "true"
else:
    print "false"
```

Comment: Mac doesn't seem to be in `retget` but in `retget['result']` (try `if 'mac' in retget['result']:`)

Comment: Thanks for for the response. I am relatively new to json so this helps alot. I was reading other sources for searching json data and they also recommended this.

Answer (score 2):

'mac' is not in the first level of your json response. You can easily check for 'mac' using an if statement like:

```
if 'mac' in retget['result']:
    print "true"
else:
    print "false"
```

You must traverse the dictionary elements in order.  The only top level element you have is 'result'.